# Initializing and populating large array in NumPy where most values are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to take a bunch of data and put it into a `Pandas` `DataFrame`. My thought was that it would be more efficient to first load it into a `NumPy` array. For this, I need about 2000 columns and 150000 rows, where the columns are of mixed type (some are `float` and some are `string`). I started by initializing a `NumPy` array like this

```
num_rows = 150000
types = [('Col1', 'float32'), ('Col2', 'U50'),..., ('Col2000', 'float32')]
arr = np.full(num_rows, np.nan, dtype=types)
```

But doing this takes a long time. Also, most of the values in this array will be `nan`. Usually, only a couple of the columns in each row will actually have a value in them. The end goal is the make this into a `pandas.DataFrame` by doing something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=arr['Col1'], columns=[i[0] for i in types])
```

Is there a more efficient way to build up `DataFrame` where most of the data will be `nan` like this?

Comment: That's `3e9` numbers. I don't think my computer has enough RAM for it.

Comment: write it into database ....

Comment: Based on the information you provided, not sure there's much to do. You could take a look at sparse matrix (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)) package from scipy, but not sure it allows for strings (and not sure it suits your needs). I think you should provide the problem you're trying to solve and consider a better solution design for this. For example, why do you need to have, in memory, `3e+9` objects allocated where most of them are None? that's just waste of memory. Maybe you could only store non-nan values, for example, and their respective indexes?

Comment: The end goal after writing to a Dataframe is to write it to a Parquet file, and I could only find a way to do that in Python by making a Dataframe first

Comment: `pandas` has a sparse feature - series and dataframe.  And in contrast to the `scipy.sparse` the fill values can be `nan`.